# dynamically coding a function to have an arbitrary number of arguments in data table

Tags: r, function, data.table

I am struggling with the syntax of map when I want to have a flexible number of columns and arguments...it's hard to code this *dynamically*.

A concrete example...

Suppose I have the following matrix, for arbitrary *J*:

```
set.seed(1) 
J=2 
n = 100
BB = data.table(r=1:n) 
for(i in seq(J)) set(x = BB, j = paste0('a',i), value = rnorm(n, 1, 7)) 
for(i in seq(J^2)) set(x = BB, j = paste0('b',i), value = rnorm(n, 1, 7)) 
for(i in seq(J)) set(x = BB, j = paste0('p',i), value = rnorm(n, 1, 7))
```

So the output is...

```
> head(BB)
   r        a1        a2         b1        b2        b3        b4          p1         p2
1: 1 -3.385177 -3.342567   3.865813  7.255716  8.521087  1.541122 -1.38746886 -3.9529776
2: 2  2.285503  1.294811  12.822113 -6.331087 14.269583 -1.078080 11.51697174 14.8010041
3: 3 -4.849400 -5.376452  12.106119 14.799362 -3.220981 -7.282696  4.69815399  0.3700092
```

I want to create a function that creates new columns from the existing columns in the following way..

(since *J*=2):

```
Lambda1 = exp(a1 + b1p1 + b2p2) 
Lambda2 = exp(a2 + b3p1 + b4p2)
```

If *J*=1 it would be:

```
Lambda1 = exp(a1 + b1p1)
```

If *J*=3…

```
Lambda1 = exp(a1 + b1p1 + b2p2 + b3p3) 
Lambda2 = exp(a2 + b4p1 + b5p2 + b6p3)
Lambda3 = exp(a3 + b7p1 + b8p2 + b9p3)
```

The output should be:

```
> head(BB)
   r        a1        a2         b1        b2        b3        b4          p1         p2       lambda1      lambda2
1: 1 -3.385177 -3.342567   3.865813  7.255716  8.521087  1.541122 -1.38746886 -3.9529776  5.547749e-17 5.862180e-10
2: 2  2.285503  1.294811  12.822113 -6.331087 14.269583 -1.078080 11.51697174 14.8010041  2.688353e+24 1.012574e+65
3: 3 -4.849400 -5.376452  12.106119 14.799362 -3.220981 -7.282696  4.69815399  0.3700092  9.401501e+24 8.370005e-11
```

**My attempted solution:**

I think it should look something like this, though the *J*^2 p parts are throwing it off.  This solution ignores it.

```
BB[,
      (paste0("lambda",seq(J))) := Map(
        function(a,b,p) exp(a + b * p),
        mget(paste0("a", seq(J))),
        mget(paste0("b", seq(J))),
        mget(paste0("p", seq(J)))
      )
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the `data.table` terminology but here a solution

```
# Find the relevant columns
colA <- which(names(BB) %in% paste0("a",seq(J)))
colB <- which(names(BB) %in% paste0("b",seq(J^2)))
colP <- which(names(BB) %in% paste0("p",seq(J)))
# Extract the a's, b's & p's
a <- BB[ ,colA, with = FALSE]
b <- BB[, colB, with = FALSE]
p <- BB[, colP, with = FALSE]
# Multiply the b's and p's - expand the p's before multiplication
bp <- b * do.call("cbind.data.frame", replicate(J, p, simplify = FALSE))
# Loop through the columns to add
for (k in 1:J){ 
  tmpLambda <- exp(rowSums(bp[,((k-1)*J+1):(k*J)]) + a[, k, with = FALSE])
  BB$tmpLambda <- tmpLambda
  names(BB)[ncol(BB)] <- paste0("Lambda",k)
}
# Result
>   head(BB)
   r        a1        a2         b1        b2        b3        b4          p1         p2       Lambda1      Lambda2
1: 1 -3.385177 -3.342567   3.865813  7.255716  8.521087  1.541122 -1.38746886 -3.9529776  5.547749e-17 5.862180e-10
2: 2  2.285503  1.294811  12.822113 -6.331087 14.269583 -1.078080 11.51697174 14.8010041  2.688353e+24 1.012574e+65
3: 3 -4.849400 -5.376452  12.106119 14.799362 -3.220981 -7.282696  4.69815399  0.3700092  9.401501e+24 8.370005e-11
```

This can wrapped into a function and/or also optimized. Here is a test run with `J=3`:

```
> str(BB)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  100 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ r      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
...
 $ Lambda1: num  6.21e-13 2.93e+23 7.46e-69 8.01e+18 1.45e+13 ...
 $ Lambda2: num  5.61e-36 1.05e+127 7.63e-32 4.36e-33 1.19e-33 ...
 $ Lambda3: num  5.84e+70 3.75e+52 1.60e-02 4.01e+33 2.51e+12 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use matrix multiplication:

```
BB[, (paste0("lambda",seq(J))) := lapply(
        as.list(matrix(unlist(mget(paste0("a", seq(J)))), nrow=1L) +
            matrix(unlist(mget(paste0("p", seq(J)))), nrow=1L) %*%
                matrix(unlist(mget(paste0("b", seq(J^2)))), ncol=J))
        , exp),
    by=1:BB[,.N]]
```

The con is that speed might not be optimal as it is going through each row of the data.table